# Spacing on top menu issue

Tags: css

For this site: https://www.citywidelaw.com/, the "Free Consultation" and Phone number should align along the top (like the logo on the left). For some reason, it's lining up under the logo.

HTML

```
<div class="nav-secondary navbar-collapse pull-right in" aria-label="Secondary" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><p class="tel hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span>Free Consultation - Call 24/7</span><a href="tel:4242482700">(424) 248-2700</a></p>
```

CSS

```
.site-header p.tel {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post more of the code so that responders can reproduce the problem. Here is a link to directives for forming a _good_ question [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
.site-title {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`.site-header p.tel` must be inside the `title-area navbar-brand` div
and to have `float: right` property.